# Count substrings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have some string

```
str = 'kkyykykyyk'
```

and I want to count how many times "kyy" and "ky" occur in this string. 
However if something overlap like in this example then I need to count only longer substring.

Mu current solution looks like this

```
k = str.count('kyy') 
y = (str.count('ky') - str.count('kyy'))
print(k, y)        # solution: 'kyy' two times AND 'ky' one time
```

Is there any shorter or "more python" approach to this problem?

Comment: For one, you can re-use the value `k` when you compute `y`, rather than calculate it again.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use the regular expression and use the `?` operator to check if an extra y occurs in the string .

That is ,we find occurences of `ky` and the check if the next value is `y` if it occurs we take it else we dont

```
>>> import re
>>> st = 'kkyykykyyk'
>>> re.findall(r'kyy?',st)
['kyy', 'ky', 'kyy']
>>> re.findall(r'kyy?',st).count('kyy')
2
>>> re.findall(r'kyy?',st).count('ky')
1
```

Comment: So my next question is if this might be preferred solution or my first attempt is good enough? Because my main goal was to simplify my code, and right now with regular expressions this might look slightly more complicated ;)

Comment: @wokadakow i think you current solution is good enough both mine and your solution will have same asymptotic runtime complexity `O(n)` and if this solution seems to complicated to you , dont use it,  but i suggest learning regular expression as it is the best tool for extracting content from strings

Comment: @wokadakow, it turns out your original code was the fastest. It can be improved using wim's suggestion in the comments. Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635138/5858851) for speed test results.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. Split on `'kyy'`. The length of the resultant array - 1 is the number of times `'kyy'` appears. Then count the occurances of `'ky'` in the resultant array by joining and splitting again.

#### Update

As @Windygound pointed out, my original code won't work if there is no occurrence of `'kyy'` in the string (nothing to split on) or if there are other letters in the string (ie `'kkyykyakyyk'`). Here is a workaround:

```
# original example 
s = 'kkyykykyyk'
print(s.split('kyy'))
#['k', 'ky', 'k']

# solution
arr = s.split('kyy')
print(len(arr)-1, len(" ".join(arr).split('ky'))-1)
```

Also, avoid naming variables `str` as that's a builtin type.

---

#### Update 2

Speed test results show that OP's code is actually the fastest. It can be improved by using @wim's suggestion in the comments to reuse the variable `k`.

**Define the functions**

```
# OP's solution
def count_ky(s):
    k = s.count('kyy') 
    y = (s.count('ky') - s.count('kyy'))
    return (k, y)

# OP's solution with @wim's suggestion
def count_ky2(s):
    k = s.count('kyy') 
    y = (s.count('ky') - k)
    return (k, y)

def count_ky_nathan(s):
    k, y = 0, 0
    for place in range(len(s)):
        if s[place:].startswith('kyy'):
            k += 1
        elif s[place:].startswith('ky'):
            y += 1
    return (k, y)

def count_ky_pault(s):
    arr = s.split('kyy')
    k = len(arr)-1
    y = len(" ".join(arr).split('ky'))-1
    return (k, y)

def count_ky_albin(s):
    k = re.findall(r'kyy?',s).count('kyy')
    y = re.findall(r'kyy?',s).count('ky')
    return (k, y)
```

**Make some random test data**

```
import random
import string
N = 1000

# pick from the letters k, y, and x
test_words = [
    ''.join(random.choice(['k', 'y', 'x']) for _ in range(random.randint(10,30)))
    for _ in range(N)
]
```

**Verify results match**

```
test_funcs = [count_ky, count_ky2, count_ky_nathan, count_ky_pault, count_ky_albin,
              count_ky_nathan2]
for tf in test_funcs:
    print reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#[687, 1424]
#[687, 1424]
#[687, 1424]
#[687, 1424]
#[687, 1424]
#[687, 1424]
```

**Speed Tests**

I left out @Nathan's 3rd solution (the *weird* one) because it didn't have the correct counts.

```
%%timeit
tf = count_ky
k, y = reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.4 ms per loop

%%timeit
tf = count_ky2
k, y = reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 ms per loop

%%timeit
tf = count_ky_nathan
k, y = reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#100 loops, best of 3: 10.1 ms per loop

%%timeit
tf = count_ky_nathan2
k, y = reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.81 ms per loop

%%timeit
tf = count_ky_pault
k, y = reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#1000 loops, best of 3: 1.63 ms per loop

%%timeit
tf = count_ky_albin
k, y = reduce(lambda x, y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(2)], [tf(s) for s in test_words])
#100 loops, best of 3: 3.79 ms per loop
```

Comment: arr.count('ky') maybe a little problem...
if s = 'kkyykymkyyk', arr will be ['k', 'kym', 'k'],
so sum(['ky' in i for i in arr]) will be a good way

Comment: @windy good catch. I've updated to hopefully account for this, but the regex solution is better.

Comment: Actually you would need `sum(i.count('ky') for i in arr)` - there may be more than one `ky` per chunk.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks, added speed test results.

Comment: The speed tests are somewhat interesting, from a theoretical point of view, but I'd point out - the OP asked about what was pythonic and/or short, not about what was fast. For a use like this, in all but the rarest of cases, having readable code - that you can modify later without having to work to figure out *how* it works - will save you *much* more time than having the fastest code.

Comment: I agree with you. In this case I think OP had the most readable _and_ fastest code to begin with.

Comment: Hm, you know, I agree with _you_ as well :)

Answer (score 0):

To count for the longer instance of substrings, I would replace the substring with some character that is invalid in the data I'm looking to go through. Then repeat with each consecutive substring.

```
string =  'kkyykykyyk'
substrings = {'kyy': 0, 'ky': 0}
for sub, val in substrings.items():
    index = string.find(sub)
    while index != -1:
        val += 1
        string = string[:index] + '###' + string[index + len(sub):]
        index = string.find(sub)
substrings[sub] = val
```

Which can print the string and dictionary as

```
k#########k
{'kyy': 2, 'ky': 1}
```

Comment: This solution only works reliably in python 3.6, since it relies on the order of `substrings.items()`.

Comment: That is correct @NathanVērzemnieks , if you wanted to use it in other versions you'd want to replace `.items()` with `.iteritems()`

Comment: `iteritems` doesn't guarantee order either!

Answer (score 0):

Trying for concise and readable rather than clever, because to me "pythonic" is very much about readability:

```
s = 'kkyykykyyk'
k, y = 0, 0
for place in range(len(s)):
    if s[place:].startswith('kyy'):
        k += 1
    elif s[place:].startswith('ky'):
        y += 1
```

For clever and short, I like this variation on @pault's split and count approach:

```
parts = s.split('kyy')
k = len(parts) - 1
y = sum(p.count('ky') for p in parts)
```

And one last weird one, just for fun:

```
nokyy = s.replace('kyy', ' ') # replace with ' ' so we don't create new matches!
noky = nokyy.replace('ky', '')
k = (len(s) - len(nokyy))//2
y = (len(nokyy) - len(noky))//2
```

Comment: the last (weird one) doesn't give the correct answer. I'm going to post some speed test results to show you how I tested it. Turns out, OP's code was the fastest.

Comment: It works for me! I just copy & pasted it and tried it now. And yeah, I'm not at all surprised that the count + count solution is fastest, but really - unless you're doing this a billion times a day, it's hardly going to matter.

Comment: Oh, silly me, I only tried it on the test string. I see why it was failling. Edited.